# error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.7

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo de texto en un notebook de jupyter pero me sale este error y no se por que

```
archivo = open('copia.txt','r')
texto=''

for linea in archivo.readlines():

 texto = texto+linea

archivo.close()
```

Error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Típicamente eso significa que el fichero que intentas leer no usa codificación utf8, que es la que python3 presupone por defecto. Si lo has creado con un editor en Windows lo más probable es que use codificación cp1252 (en esta codificación el códig 0xd3 representa la Ó, ¿hay una Ó en tu archivo de texto?). Puedes especificar una codificación a la hora de abrir el fichero: `open("copia.txt", "r", encoding="cp1252")`

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tu texto contiene caracteres especiales, que el encoding por defecto `utf-8` no puede leer. Puedes simplemente añadir el parametro `error='replace'` a tu instruccion `open()`:

```
archivo = open('copia.txt','r', errors='replace')
texto=''

for linea in archivo.readlines():
    texto = texto+linea

archivo.close()
```

Esto te deberia funcionar. Por otro lado, si prefieres eliminarlos, puedes usar `errors='ignore'`.